# See changes since branch was created directly in Visual Studio 2019/2022 (or Rider)

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

When I create a feature branch in VS and don't commit changes, every file I change will get marked with a little red checkmark in solution explorer and I can super easy see what changes Ive made.

But as soon as I make one commit, all that goodness is gone. Its recommended to make commits little and often so is there a way to get this functionality, but since branch was created?

I know that you can do git diff, but it would be good to get it directly in VS. I would be prepared to move to Rider, if its available there

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the history (i.e. showing the list of commits), you can select two commits from the list, and then right-click and Compare Commits.  This will open a window comparing every file that changed between those commits.

(Branch History can be accessed either directly or as part of the Manage Branches item in the Git top level menu; Manage Branches is also available in the Git Changes window.)

Comment: yes, that all fine and dandy, for a single file, but what Im looking for is the nice overview in VS solution explorer. Say that you work with 10 files in a feature branch. Before your first commit, you can easily find them, because they all have that red check box. Once commiting, they all look the same

Comment: I was referring to looking at the branch history, not a specific file.  The comparison view showing the diffs includes all files affected by the selected commit range.  This can't be shown in Solution Explorer directly as it only shows the current files on disk.